# how to deal with the situation while DB Down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

#### how to deal with the situation while DB Down!

Description:

Server:Passenger

Imagine:
While you app'running,one of the dbs down,so this rails goes wrong,when new request to the website,there will be new rails to answer the request(but DB still down),so it's keeping going wrong till all rails go wrong!

#### so whats the solution under this situation?

Comment: You want the app to run normally?  It sounds like you just want to show a custom error page.

Answer (score 2):

just update your `/public/500.html`

There are `404.html`, `422.html`, `500.html` page in your `public` folder, whenever any error occurs depending on the error code one of there html is shown to the user.

You need to give same look and feel as your application with related message so that user should get acknowledge something bad is happens and at the same time should connected to the your application.

Comment: hi,sorry,i didnt describe the problem correctly before.now ive update the question.thx!